# Shiro Logout - org.apache.shiro.session.UnknownSessionException

Tags: shiro

I have currently an issue with Apache Shiro for logout:

Here my Shiro.ini

```
[main]
#### Session
sessionIdCookie=org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.SimpleCookie
#sessionIdCookie.path = /
sessionIdCookie.httpOnly = true
sessionIdCookie.name = sid
sessionIdCookie.domain = localhost
sessionIdCookie.maxAge=28800000
sessionIdCookie.secure = true
sessionIdCookie.sameSite = NONE

sessionManager=org.apache.shiro.web.session.mgt.DefaultWebSessionManager
sessionManager.sessionIdCookie=$sessionIdCookie
sessionManager.sessionIdCookieEnabled=true
securityManager.sessionManager=$sessionManager
# Session Timeout nach 8 Stunden
sessionManager.globalSessionTimeout= 28800000

sessionListener1= de.dpunkt.myaktion.util.MySessionListener1
sessionManager.sessionListeners=$sessionListener1

# Session validation = 5 minutes
sessionManager.sessionValidationInterval = 300000


#sessionManager = org.apache.shiro.web.session.mgt.DefaultWebSessionManager
#securityManager.sessionMode=native


sessionValidationScheduler=org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.ExecutorServiceSessionValidationScheduler
sessionValidationScheduler.interval = 60000
sessionValidationScheduler.sessionManager=$sessionManager
sessionManager.sessionValidationScheduler=$sessionValidationScheduler
sessionManager.deleteInvalidSessions=true
#sessionFactory=org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.OnlineSessionFactory
#sessionManager.sessionFactory=$sessionFactory
#securityManager.subjectDAO.sessionStorageEvaluator.sessionStorageEnabled = false




# password hashing specification, put something big for hasIterations
sha512Matcher = org.apache.shiro.authc.credential.HashedCredentialsMatcher
sha512Matcher.hashAlgorithmName=SHA-512
sha512Matcher.hashIterations=1

# Configure JDBC realm datasource.
...

# Realm for Token Login
....

# AuthStrategy
authenticator = org.apache.shiro.authc.pam.ModularRealmAuthenticator
authcStrategy = org.apache.shiro.authc.pam.AtLeastOneSuccessfulStrategy

authenticator = org.apache.shiro.authc.pam.ModularRealmAuthenticator
securityManager.authenticator = $authenticator
securityManager.authenticator.authenticationStrategy = $authcStrategy
securityManager.realms = $jdbcRealm, $tcRealm 

# Caching
cacheManager = org.apache.shiro.cache.MemoryConstrainedCacheManager
securityManager.cacheManager = $cacheManager

# Using default form based security filter org.apache.shiro.web.filter.authc.FormAuthenticationFilter
authc = org.apache.shiro.web.filter.authc.FormAuthenticationFilter
authc.loginUrl = /common/login.jsf
authc.successUrl = /portal/dashboard.jsf


# Redirect to an access denied page if user does not have access rights
#[roles]
#roles.unauthorizedUrl = /common/access-denied.jsf
#perms.unauthorizedUrl = /accessdenied.jsp




## OTHER
/WEB-INF/layout/portal/** = authc
/portal/** = authc
```

And here is my Controller Class:

```cs
    @SessionScoped
    @Named
    public class LoginBean implements Serializable {
    
    private Subject currentUserShiro;
    
        public void logout() {
    
            LOGGER.info("START logout");
    
            try {
    
                FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
                HttpSession httpSession = (HttpSession) facesContext.getExternalContext().getSession(false);
                ServletContext application = httpSession.getServletContext();
      
                // Shiro User
                currentUserShiro.logout();
                currentUserShiro = null;
                
                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("/common/login.jsf"); 
    
    
            }
    
            catch (UnavailableSecurityManagerException e) {
                LOGGER.info("UnavailableSecurityManagerException");
            }
    
            catch (UnknownSessionException e) {
                LOGGER.info("Unknown Session");
            }
    
            catch (ExpiredSessionException e) {
                LOGGER.info("Session is expired");
            }
    
            catch (StoppedSessionException e) {
                LOGGER.info("Session stopped");
            }
    
            catch (NullPointerException e) {
            }
    
            catch (Exception e) {
                LOGGER.error(ExceptionUtils.getFullStackTrace(e));
            }
    
            LOGGER.info("END logout");
        }
```

After I press the logout button, I´m getting this error message:

> org.apache.shiro.session.UnknownSessionException: There is no session with id [32767ef1-b285-4dc3-8

Can anybody help here? Is there anything which I haven´t considered?
It seems the logout is successful and the user is not able to go back and have the same permission, but everytime I´m getting this Exception.

Comment: Can you please elaborate how you obtain `currentUserShiro`?

Comment: It´s just login: `currentUserShiro = sessionUserServiceBean.login(username, password);` Function "login" is than using `UsernamePasswordToken token = new UsernamePasswordToken(username, password);`

Answer (score 0):

Alright, you called the logout session on a Subject which is not known to Shiro.

To obtain the current subject, please use `Subject currentUser = SecurityUtils.getSubject();` -- the same as for the login method where you call `currentUser.login( token );).

Now, with the logout method, you only need to use:

```java
  Subject currentUser = SecurityUtils.getSubject();
  currentUser.logout();
```

... plus a try-catch.

That said, see if you can eliminate your instance field `private Subject currentUserShiro`. It should not be needed (at least in the code you showed us).

Reference: 
https://shiro.apache.org/subject.html